# break into multiple rows a dataset with multiple columns in a single row - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a complete dataset stacked in just one row. This dataset should have 7 columns and 360 rows.

just for example, the first positions are:

df=[1, 14/02/2013, 3.305,55, 206,05, 25, 3.536,60, 349.027,78, 2, 14/03/2013, 3.299,07, 205,59, 25, 3.529,66, 348.055,56, 3, 14/04/2013, 3.292,59, 205,13, 25, 3.522,72, 347.083,34, 4, 14/05/2013, 3.286,11, 204,67, 25, 3.515,78, 346.111,12, 5, 14/06/2013, 3.279,63, 204,22, 25, 3.508,84, 345.138,90]

and I need them as:

- 1, 14/02/2013, 3.305,55, 206,05, 25, 3.536,60, 349.027,78
- 2, 14/03/2013, 3.299,07, 205,59, 25, 3.529,66, 348.055,56
- 3, 14/04/2013, 3.292,59, 205,13, 25, 3.522,72, 347.083,34
- 4, 14/05/2013, 3.286,11, 204,67, 25, 3.515,78, 346.111,12
- 5, 14/06/2013, 3.279,63, 204,22, 25, 3.508,84, 345.138,90

How can I do that in python/pandas?

thanks.

Comment: Can you update your example so the data can be pasted directly into someone else's code?  For example, it looks like you have dates: are your dates stored as strings?  If so, they should have quotes around them.  Otherwise on pasting they're going to be treated as division operations.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. You haven't even provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy array_split() to divide the len of the list by the number of columns you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(d,len(d)/7))
```

Output

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
2  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` and `iter`

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[iter(d)] * 7)))

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
2  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

---

Using `np.reshape`
This requires that the length of `d` be a multiple of `7` otherwise this breaks.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(d, (-1, 7)))

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
2  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

Fix the finicky bit... but will only grab upto the most recent group of 7

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(d[:len(d) // 7 * 7], (-1, 7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most straightforward solution is to use *reshape* method from *Numpy*.
The first parameter is *-1* - create as many rows as needed, the second is *7* - the
number of columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 7))
```

Maybe you should also pass *columns* parameter, to set meaningful column names.